# ListDataTable rowIndex not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to build a `<p:dataTable>` with row count but for some reason it shows only the first index in every row. Here is my code:

### index.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable value="#{personBean.personListAsModel}" var="person">
  <p:column headerText="No">
    <h:outputText value="#{personBean.personListAsModel.rowIndex + 1}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="Last name">
    <h:outputText value="#{person.lastName}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column headerText="First name">
    <h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable
```

### PersonBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped //The scope doesn't matter (I think)
public class PersonBean () {
    private List<Person> personList;

    public PersonBean() {
        personList = new ArrayList<>();

        // populate the list with Person objects (it's just a POJO with first and last name)
    }

    // get/set for personList

    public ListDataModel<Person> getPersonListAsModel() {
        return new ListDataModel(personList);
    }
}
```

But when I display the table the result is something like this:

```
| No | Last Name | First Name |
|----|-----------|------------|
| 1  | Smith     | John       |
| 1  | Perez     | Juan       |
| 1  | Stallman  | Richard    |
| 1  | Gosling   | James      |
| 1  | Cagatay   | Civici     |
| 1  | Doe       | Jane       |
```

Is there something am I missing? Any guide/help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Other Solution [binding="#{table}" By BalusC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633008/jsf-2-datatable-row-index-without-datamodel)

Answer (score 2):

The row index is stored in `DataModel` and defaults to `-1`. You're creating a new `ListDataModel` instance in getter method. `UIData` components calls getter method on every iteration.

Just stop creating models and doing other business logic in getter methods.

As your bean is view scoped and `DataModel` is not serializable, best is to lazy load it.

```
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Person> personList;
    private transient DataModel<Person> personListAsModel;

    @EJB
    private PersonService personService;

    @PostConstruct    
    public void init() {
        personList = personService.list();
    }

    public ListDataModel<Person> getPersonListAsModel() {
        if (personListAsModel == null) {
            personListAsModel = new ListDataModel(personList);
        }
        return personListAsModel;
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [How and when should I load the model from database for h:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765853/when-should-i-load-the-collection-from-database-for-hdatatable)
- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/)
- [How to display row numbers in JSF table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948854/how-to-display-row-numbers-in-jsf-table/)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem (at least for now) by doing:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{personBean.personList}" var="person">
  <p:column headerText="No">
    <h:outputText value="#{personBean.personList.indexOf(person) + 1}"/>
  </p:column>
...
```

As I see, it's a clean option, but remains as a mystery why `ListDataModel` doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Not getting this line :

```
 <h:outputText value="#{personBean.personListAsModel.rowIndex + 1}"/>
```

that's you are trying to access rowIndex of a datamodel but you are not iterating in this line so it is giving you index 1 always....you are iterating from datatable and you have defined var for that so use that

```
<h:outputText value="#{person.rowIndex + 1}"/>
```

it should be resolved lemme know if not.